# why this property doesn't want to be deleated

Tags: javascript

Wrote this code only for experimental purpose. here i used Object.defineProperty to create a property called `'fullName'` and using set i defined another property to person called `middleName` . I have to pass value to `middleName` through `fullName`.Both of them has enumerable property `TRUE`,so that `for..in` loop can access it.But then i wanted to delete the middleName property from the object.But it is still there.Why it is still there??

```js
(function(){
  person = {
    firstName: 'will',
    lastName: 'Smith'
  };

  Object.defineProperty(person,'fullName',{

    set:function(mid){
      Object.defineProperty(person,'middleName',{
        value     : mid,
        enumerable: true,
        writeable : false
      });
    },
    get:function(){
      document.write(this.middleName);
    },
    enumerable:true
  });

  person.fullName='lol';
  person.fullName; 
  document.write(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(person)+'</br>'); 

  for(key in person){
    document.write(key+'</br>');
  }  

  document.write('\n');   
  delete (person.middleName);
  document.write(person.middleName+'</br>');

  for(key in person){
    document.write(key+'</br>');
  }
})()
```

Comment: `delete` operator is intended to use with **variables**. `person.middleName + '</br>'` you trying to delete is an **expression**

Comment: that was a typing mistake when i was editing the post .it was not included in actual code.I have edited the post.check it please

Comment: @hindmost—I think you mean the [*delete* operator](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.1) is for deleting object properties, not variables (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using [*Object.defineProperty*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.6), the configurable attribute is set to false by default (see [*ToPropertyDescriptor*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.10.5), step 4) so the *middleName* property is not deletable.

Note that in:

```
delete (person.middleName);
```

the parenthesis are redundant, it should be written:

```
delete person.middleName;
```

A simple example is:

```
// Create object o
var o = {};

// Define property a with value bar
Object.defineProperty(o, 'a', {
  value : 'bar'
});

console.log(o.a); // bar

// Since the configurable property of a was not set, it defaults to false
// so it can't be deleted
delete o.a;

console.log(o.a); // bar

// Create property b with value fum and configurable true
Object.defineProperty(o, 'b', {
  value : 'fum',
  configurable: true
});

console.log(o.b); // fum

// Since b's configurable attribute is true, it can be deleted
delete o.b;

console.log(o.hasOwnProperty('b')); // false
console.log(o.b); // undefined
```